# Inverse Laplace transform in R

Tags: r, time-series, fft

I am trying to do some computations using Laplace transforms in R. I used the
continued fractions approach to compute Laplace transform of a birth-death
process as described in [Abate 1999](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/continuedfractions99.pdf). But I cannot find a simple numerical routine to compute the inverse Laplace transform (evaluated at 0 in my case). Does anyone have ideas on how to do this in R?

Comment: Although this is a little late, sending this question over to SO may give it better exposure among R experts who might be able to contribute additional suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing inverse Laplace transforms numerically is tricky. I remember seeing some relatively recent results [on the ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=212066.212068&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=70852297&CFTOKEN=54365017). Googling around a bit, I found some 
[Python code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576934-numerical-inversion-of-the-laplace-transform-using/) implementing one of these algorithms. Maybe you can adapt it to your purposes.